# Add additional number manually in SQL aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
TempC
----
32
27
36
30
```

```
SELECT STDEV(TempC) 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Time BETWEEN dateadd(HOUR, -4, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

In the table above, I can get the standard deviation easily using `STDEV()` function, but now there is an additional number I want to add to the table before calculating its standard deviation. The additional number is not from database but written manually in SQL query.

```
TempC
----
32
27
36
30
37 (manually added number)
```

How can I do it efficiently?

Comment: Use a standard deviation formula based on other aggregates.

Comment: Try `(sqrt((count(TempC)+1) * (sum(TempC * TempC) + C * C) - (sum(TempC) + C) * (sum(TempC) + C)) / count(TempC))`

Comment: use  `UNION ALL`

Comment: See rapid calculation methods. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods Yes, you can use `union all` for a single group. If you don't know how many rows in the outout then it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `UNION ALL` to manually add the required value

```
SELECT STDEV(TempC) 
FROM   (
           SELECT TempC FROM myTable
           UNION ALL
           SELECT TempC = 37
       ) T
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly and very easy as well.